# least value of $3m+n$

Tags: calculus

> If $mx^2+nx+6=0$ does not have two disticnt real
>
> roots. Then least value of $3m+n$ is

Try: Let $3m+n=t,$ Then our equation convert into

$mx^2+(t-3m)x+6=0$

Equation does not have real roots

So we have $(t-3m)^2-24m\leq 0$

$$t^2-6mt+9m^2-24m\geq 0$$

now i am struck here, could some help me how to solve it , Thanks

Comment: Is there something unwritten here disallowing you from taking $m = n = 0$?  I'm looking at this and found that $m \ge 0$, so $3m + n$ is minimized when $m = n = 0$, which satisfies the "$mx^2 + nx + 6 = 0$ doesn't have two distinct real roots" condition.

Comment: @tilper $x^2-4x + 6$ also works, giving $3m+n = -1$. So it can be smaller than what you get from $m = n = 0$. That's what's stopping you.

Comment: Ah, you're right, $n$ could be negative.  Totally spaced on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $n^2\le24m$

$3m+n\ge\dfrac{ n^2}8+ n=\dfrac{(n+4)^2-16}8\ge-2$